# Get WP logged-in user from yii2 application

Tags: wordpress, yii2

I have WP & yii2 application installed on the same server, same domain. I would like to get WP currently logged-in user from within yii2 application.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
require_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
require_once('../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php');

echo wp_get_current_user()->ID;
```

Just make sure the path is OK, so that you are able to require the files successfully.

Comment: This worked, thanks!
It was enough to include wp-config.php from WP folder.
But I had to define COOKIEPATH to parent folder, so yii2 application will have access to WP cookie as well.